# How can I tell when a tire was manufactured?

Tags: tires

Unused tires harden and deteriorate quickly in harsh desert climates. When I shop for tires I want to make sure I get ones that are as fresh as possible from the factory without trusting the sales representatives too much.

Is it possible to tell when a tire was made just by looking at it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most legislations require tire manufacturers to list the *week* and year of manufacture as a 4-digit code on the sidewall.

[image: Tire Rack Pic]

In the example picture, the last four digits of the tire identification number (5107) refer to the week and year of manufacture (*WWYY* format).

This means that the tire in the image was manufactured in Week 51 of 2007 (mid-December).

Comment: I could have sworn this info was on here before, but I cannot find it (which I bet you couldn't either). Good information! +1/+1