# Determine Tire Age

Tags: tires

I want to determine how old the tires on my car are. I understand there is an age code on each tire. But what if the age code is on the inner side? Is there some code I can use on both sides of the tire?

Answer (score 3):

The age code is only on one sidewall. There is no requirement that it be installed facing out. I have used a mirror to read the code when installed on inside. Tirerack.com has a good article on how to interpret the codes. There is no regulation concerning how many years should be left on a vehicle in the US. Some say 6 yrs max other say 10 years. I have heard that the UK has a 6 year max installed life limit.

Comment: Okay 2 of my tires are installed with code facing in - I still have to stick my head under the car with the mirror, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/16023/675) on  how to decode the age of a tire.

Regarding how to read the code if it is on the inside of the wheel, [Fred Wilson's answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/19758/675) should be adequate: use a small mirror and flashlight to locate the code and determine the age.

One thing which I have noticed is that some tire manufacturers (especially the less-reputable ones) will *not* print the manufacturing code on the tire, especially if there is no local legislation mandating them to do so. This is why it is a good idea to insist on seeing the code at the time of purchase.